# Changes in email template are saved, but not used (cache?)

Tags: caching, emails, 9

I'm usually trying to find an answer/clue on my own, and usually it works, but at this time search is fruitless.
So I'm trying to edit a welcome email text, using /admin/config/people/accounts section. Changes are saved, if I reload a page - I can see the new version of the text.
But the actual email is using the old version - before the changes!

If I'm honest, I don't even know how to debug something like this, so I tried all I could think of:

- Disabled SMTP Authentication - didn't change anything
- Tried to translate that very text in /admin/config/regional/translate section - didn't work
- Enabled HTML markup - the emails are now in HTML but the text is still not changed
- Tried to edit another email template (of the message that's being sent to admins notifying that the account awaits moderation) - to no surprise, the changes didn't work here as well
- And of course, flushed all caches I know of multiple times. That also didn't do anything.

Could anybody give me a clue? What am I missing?